# How does Java process the expression x = x - (x = x - 1)?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I just tested the following code:

```
int x = 90;

x = x - (x = x - 1);
System.out.print(x);
```

It prints 1.

As far as I understand, things go in the following order:

1. `x - 1` is computed and stored to a temporary variable in memory.
2. `x` is assigned the result from the temporary variable from item 1.
3. Then `x - the new value of x` is calculated.
4. The result is assigned to `x`;

I don't understand why `x` from which we subtract the result of item 2 still has initial value after item 2. What am I missing?

Comment: `x = x - (x = x - 1);` == `x = 90 - (x = x - 1);` == `x = 90 - (x = 90 - 1);` == `x = 90 - (x = 89);` == == `x = 90 - 89;` == `x = 1;`

Comment: @Matsemann because a) I was too lazy to look for the JLS reference (which in my opinion should be included in a proper answer), b) I am pretty sure that this is some duplicate of some question somewhere on SO and c) it is too short to be a real answer and again, I was too lazy to formulate a proper text, explaining it in detail.

Comment: @Turing85, I would have accepted it if it was an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

You are doing `90 - (90 - 1)` => `1`

It's important to not confuse precedence with order of evaluation. They are related but not the same.

---

EDIT

As @ruakh points out, the JLS spec put it differently to the tutorial above.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15‌​.7.

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.
>
> If the operator is a compound-assignment operator (§15.26.2), then evaluation of the left-hand operand includes both remembering the variable that the left-hand operand denotes and fetching and saving that variable's value for use in the implied binary operation.
>
> If evaluation of the left-hand operand of a binary operator completes abruptly, no part of the right-hand operand appears to have been evaluated.

Rather than say the assignment is evaluated right to left, it treats assignment as first a store of the variable to be updated, then an evaluation of the value and finally an assignment.

Comment: +1, though I disagree with the quoted statement. `foo().bar = baz().bar` will call `foo()` *before* calling `baz()`.

Comment: @ruakh I guess it counts `.` or `[` as an operator which is evaluated first left to right.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. My point was that the left-hand-side of the assignment, `foo().bar`, is evaluated before the right-hand-side, `baz().bar`. The details of `.` are not really relevant to that.

Comment: @ruakh the . Is evaluated left to right first and the assignment right to left after.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what is meant by saying that an operator is evaluated from left to right. (Or maybe I am.) I take it to mean that the left operand is evaluated before the right operand. How are you interpreting it? (Can you give an example of a piece of code that behaves a certain way because assignment is  evaluated right-to-left, that would behave differently if it were evaluated left-to-right?)

Comment: Addendum: The spec agrees with me that evaluation is *always* left-to-right -- no exception for assignment operators: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7. So the passage that you quote is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We start with:

```
int x = 90;
x = x - (x = x - 1);
```

The first assignment operator = has low precedence,  so the right side is evaluated first.

The right side of  x = x - (x = x - 1) is x - b where b is (x = x - 1)

This right side is evaluated left to right, so it becomes 90 - b

Then b, which is (x = x - 1), is evaluated.  Once again the assignment operator has lowest precedence, so it becomes (x = 90 - 1) or (x = 89)

Substituting back, we have 90 - (x = 89) which is 90 - 89 which is 1.  Finally, the first assignment operator is evaluated and x becomes 1.  You'll notice that the other assignment operator (x = 89) had no effect on the overall operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
   int x = 90;
   x = x - (x = x - 1);
   System.out.print(x);`
Here
x = 90 Goes in two section in your code.
First x=90 - , Second  (x=90-1);
Then x=90  - , x = 89 
Then x= 90 - 89
       System.out.Print(x);
that is x=1;
```